# Forcing Encoding.UTF8.GetString to throw an ArgumentException

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, utf-8, character-encoding, asp.net-core-3.1

From [the `Encoding.GetString(Byte[])` MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getstring?view=netcore-3.1#System_Text_Encoding_GetString_System_Byte___) I find that it can throw an `ArgumentException` if:

> The byte array contains invalid Unicode code points.

What test data can I throw at the method to cause such an exception?

I started trying a couple of inputs based on [this other question about "invalid unicode characters"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/247739/25934), e.g.:

```
[Fact]
public void Checkit()
{
    // Does not throw an ArgumentException :'(
    var result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(new byte[] { 0x80, 0x81 });
}
```

and

```
[Fact]
public void Checkit()
{
    // Does not throw an ArgumentException :'(
    var result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(new byte[] { 0xc2, 0xc2 });
}
```

but neither `Fact` fails with an `ArgumentException`.

I also found [a whole bunch of supposedly invalid byte sequences in the dotnet runtime repo tests](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/3155ca2dfa20e11949f24e439b54ba1816be3c22/src/libraries/System.Text.Encoding/tests/UTF8Encoding/UTF8EncodingDecode.cs#L115-L340) which won't throw said ArgumentException (upon testing a couple).

The *trigger* for me asking is that I have code that *uses* `GetString(Byte[])` and I want to see how it handles bad input by writing a unit test for it. But the *reason* for me asking is really curiosity (I can surely rewrite my unit test slightly to fix my immediate problem).

**What "*invalid Unicode code points*" can I throw at `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Byte[])` to cause an `ArgumentException`?**

Comment: while don't know a wrong combination of bytes to trigger the exception, I suggest you to use random bytes in a loop -- I guess you'll find ones in a few seconds.

Comment: The default instance (`Encoding.UTF8`) is instantiated with `throwOnInvalidBytes` passed as `false`, so you might not be able to get it to throw until you `new` up an instance and pass `true`.

Comment: Yep... `new UTF8Encoding(false, true).GetString(new byte[] { 0xc2, 0xc2 })` throws an exception.

Comment: Thx @madreflection! That is actually the _answer_ to the question I didn't know I should've asked ("Why is my sample not throwing an exception?"). Care to quickly post it so I can give you them sweet karma points? :) .... Then again, it seems to give me a `DecoderFallbackException` not an `ArgumentException`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `UTF8Encoding` class is *capable* of throwing an exception but apparently it doesn't mention that you need an instance configured to throw one, and the default instance (`Encoding.UTF8`) is not configured that way.

Modifying your Facts ever so slightly...

```cs
[Fact]
public void Checkit()
{
    // Throws DecoderFallbackException
    var result = new UTF8Encoding(false, true).GetString(new byte[] { 0x80, 0x81 });
}

[Fact]
public void Checkit()
{
    // Throws DecoderFallbackException
    var result = new UTF8Encoding(false, true).GetString(new byte[] { 0xc2, 0xc2 });
}
```

The first argument (`encoderShouldEmitUTF8Identifier`) won't affect these tests because it has to do with the inverse operation.  If you're also looking at how `GetBytes` works, pass `false` to omit the preamble or `true` to include it (which is how `Encoding.UTF8` is configured).

The exception type you'll get is one of the other exception types documented, `DecoderFallbackException`, which is thrown when:

> A fallback occurred (for more information, see Character Encoding in .NET)
> -and-
> DecoderFallback is set to DecoderExceptionFallback.

<s>So if you can change whatever `DecoderFallback` is, you might be able to get that `ArgumentException` you were looking for.</s>

Apparently, as you discovered on your own, `DecoderFallbackException` is a subclass of `ArgumentException`, so you're all set.

Comment: Thx again for your help and an answer! Once/if I find a way to actually get the `ArgumentException` that's documented, I'll also accept it.

Comment: I'll see what I can do to help with that.

Comment: Waiiittt a second! A `DecoderFallbackException` _is_ a subclass of `ArgumentException`. So we were already there. Thx again so much for your help!